# Can I access an Android View's text buffer more directly?

Tags: android, view

Let's say i have the statement

output.setText(output.getText() + p1 + "\n");

Does a method exist which allows me to more efficiently access, modify, and update a View's text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to find an easier method of appending text to a `TextView` or `EditText`, you can use this:

```
TextView tV = (TextView) findById(resourceId);
tV.append(CharSequence cs)
tV.append(CharSequence cs, int start, int end)
```

It is likely to do the exact same in the background, but it will clean up your code a bit. `EditText` inherits the method from `TextView`, so the same applies there.

See also
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#append(java.lang.CharSequence)